# Zigbee sniffer to Penetrate Testing Zigbee network at home

Tags: usb, zigbee

I have installed Smart home temperature sensors with Zigbee network. I am trying to do a Penetrate Testing. I have installed WirelessShark. I purchased a CEL ME357 USB stick. But
I could not find driver for it.  To proceed the test, can anyone suggest a working solution for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to know exactly what you are trying to acheive, or what OS you are using etc, but hopefully the following helps answer your question.

> I purchased a CEL ME357 USB stick. But I could not find driver for it.

Drivers for the CEL MeshConnect sticks are available on their website for both Windows and Mac -:

http://www.cel.com/parts.do?command=load&idRootPart=2707

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and there are downloads.

> I have installed WirelessShark

There is sniffer software available that will work with standard Silabs software and runs on Java (so is portable across most operating systems). You can find the Java sniffer software which will work with Wireshark here -:

https://github.com/zsmartsystems/com.zsmartsystems.zigbee.sniffer

Note though that you will need to program firmware into the CEL stick as it does not come pre-installed. This normally requires that you purchase a developers kit from Silicon Labs in order to a) get the hardware, and b) get access to the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easyest way is to use [Zboss sniffer](https://zboss.dsr-wireless.com/downloads/index/zboss) with Wireshark and one of the supported USB 802.15.4 dongle. For example TI CC2531EMK. It will need to be flashed with a specific firmware so you will also need a CC-debugger to perform programming.

An other solution is to use the [Ubisys](https://www.ubisys.de/en/products/for-zb-product-developer/wireshark-usb-stick/) sniffer dongle directly with Wireshark but it is not same price.

I suppose there are lots of other sniffers but I personally used these and the first one is especially easy to setup.